# How to use vimeo player without showing the link when there is problem with network or other erros

Tags: android-videoview, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player, vimeo-android

I am using vimeo player in my android app. I am using webview of vimeo player. It works fine in my app. But if due to some reason,netwrk problem arises or I turn of my mobile data, the webview of the vimeo player shows the link of the video. This should not be happened in my case as I am selling online videos. If someone gets my video link, they can simply watch that video outside my app. But I don't want that. I gone through the net , no answer are there. kiny help me if you .. Thanks

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with android development.  However, Is there a way to listen for that system event and remove the window entirely upon loss of internet?

Comment: Yeah, we can detect the error in android version above Api 26, but for lower version, we cannot detect the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are selling videos online then as per my view not to use webview instead of that you can use custom video player and can pass vimeo video url to this player at the time of playing.

1. For this you can save video url at server end so that if more visitors there, you will provide same video path from backend and this will save you the no. of api hits  (that is limited for Vimeo)
2. On custom player you have full control on all events and people will not identify from where these videos are hosted.